# Modify launcher VM for Dataflow flex template

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We are using Dataflow Flex Templates (`FROM gcr.io/dataflow-templates-base/python3-template-launcher-base:20210120_RC00`) and storing the images on our own artifactory instead of the google cloud Container Registry. Until here everything works fine but if I do run the dataflow flex template I receive the following error message during the creation of the launcher VM:

```
"/usr/bin/docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://artifactory.xxx.com/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority."
```

The error occurs due to using our own artifactory having own signed certifactes.
When I ssh into the launcher VM and do a `docker ps` I can see the following image running:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                                                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS    NAMES
a34c29a8b8b8        gcr.io/dataflow-templates-base/template-launcher-logger:flex_templates_base_image_release_20200803_RC00   "/opt/google/dataflo…"   45 seconds ago      Up 42 seconds                agitated_shirley
```

I could not find a way to extend these `gcr.io/dataflow-templates-base/template-launcher-logger` image.
Is there a way to change the image of the launcher VM so that it is possible to install custom certificates?

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think it's possible to customize the launcher VM (and in the future there may not even be a VM to customize, e.g. the container could be started by something like [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run)).  I would recommend mirroring the images to gcr.

Comment: Thanks - It looks like the only way so we will continue with mirroring it